# find the element in the source html code for invalid login case in protractor

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm trying to write a simple "failed login" test in protractor. The thing is, i can't point (don't know how), to the specific string in the source code.

I tried all kinds of things like: cssContainingText, to equal, get text and etc. (maybe it's ok, but i did that wrong).

The test:

```
describe('login to POC', function() {


  it('should login to POC', function() {
    browser.get('http://emeaherz-swaqal:8080/web-client/login.html#/login');

    element(by.model('echos_username')).sendKeys('super1');

    element(by.model('echos_password')).sendKeys('super');

    element(by.id('loginButton')).click();


    expect(by.id('action-messages')).getText('The following error(s) occurred:').isPresent()).toBe(true);


  });

});
```

Please look on the source code.

I'm really need the suggestion here!

[html source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRCeM.jpg)

the error i'm getting is:

@alecxe

1) login to POC should login to POC
   Message:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".action-messages")
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".action-messages")
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object]. (/localfs/Poc/qapoc1/ECHOS-V2-POC/tests/fail_login.js:16:18)
Error
    at [object Object]. (/localfs/Poc/qapoc1/ECHOS-V2-POC/tests/fail_login.js:6:3)
    at Object. (/localfs/Poc/qapoc1/ECHOS-V2-POC/tests/fail_login.js:1:63)

Finished in 4.942 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `element` call and I think you can just expect the text of the error message. Replace:

```
expect(by.id('action-messages')).getText('The following error(s) occurred:').isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

with:

```
expect($('#action-messages ul li').getText()).toEqual("Sorry, your username ...");
```

Comment: i tried 

expect($('#action-messages ul li').getText()).toEqual('Sorry, your username and/or password are incorrect. Please try again.');

and  (with " ")

expect($('#action-messages ul li').getText()).toEqual("Sorry, your username and/or password are incorrect. Please try again.");

and it's still not working.

Comment: @tomerqa what do you mean by still not working? What errors are you getting? Thanks!

Comment: The following error:
Failures:
 1) login to POC should login to POC
Message:
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".action-messages")
Stacktrace:
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".action-messages")
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/localfs/.../tests/fail_login.js:16:18)
Error
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/localfs/.../tests/fail_ login.js:6:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/localfs/.../tests/fail_login.js:1:63
Finished in 4.98 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

Comment: @tomerqa but why are you using `.action-messages` selector? I did not suggest that. The selector I've suggested is `#action-messages ul li`.

Comment: i did! that the error not me!.... please look on the screenshot in the following link:  https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=4050760570&photo_id=9078332200 @alecxe